# How do I use the Google Maps coordinate system?

Tags: r

I don't understand how the coordinate system works in the *plotGoogleMaps* package.

For example, lets say I wanna plot these coordinates (Eiffel Tower):

```
lat <- 48.858264 # y
lon <- 2.294557 # x
```

Here's my code:

```
coords <- data.frame(lon, lat)
coordinates(coords) <- ~ lat + lon
proj4string(coords) <- CRS('+init=epsg:28992')
plotGoogleMaps(coords, filename = 'map.htm')
```

However the location I obtain is completely different to what i was expecting. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Inverted lat and lon

Comment: Your coordinates placed me on a field near La Celle-Saint-Cyr in France. Interestingly, when I searched for the approximate place in Google Maps and used the coordinates provided (47.975211, 3.313445) again in your code, it placed me in the exact same spot. Weird stuff.

Comment: Sometimes the order of lat + long / long + lat has thrown me. Most uses are long (x) + lat (y), but Google uses lat + long for some reason. Worth a check?

Comment: BTW, the longitude is 2.294577 and the latitude is 48.858264 for the Eiffel Tower in Paris.

Comment: Also, you seem to provide EPSG:4326 coordinates (WGS84) but use the EPSG:28992 in your projection. See http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/ and http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/28992/.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the scale of your `lat/lon`-values. If I put on vastly different values (like 2000/500), I'm still placed somewhere in France (in a different place though).

Comment: @OcuS It works when using `'+init=espg:4326'`, good job!

Comment: @LeoP. I'm making this an answer. Spatial References are hard, but fun. You might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to provide [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84) coordinates (WGS84) but use the [EPSG:28992](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/28992) in your projection.

Try to change

```
proj4string(coords) <- CRS('+init=epsg:28992')
```

to

```
proj4string(coords) <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')
```